# Why doesn't mySQL DROP TABLE work?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to run this procedure in mySQL Query Browser (v5.0.6):

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `M_ORIGRES`.`RemoveDups` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `M_ORIGRES`.`RemoveDups` ()
BEGIN


     drop table if exists M_ORIGRES.RSLFix;

     #copy the xID of duplicated records into a temp table
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS M_ORIGRES.RSLFix
     SELECT n1.xID AS TempxID FROM M_ORIGRES.`Results Signed List` AS n1, M_ORIGRES.`Results Signed List` AS n2
            WHERE n1.xID > n2.xID
                  AND n1.`Import Accession Number` = n2.`Import Accession Number`
                  AND n1.`Import Date` = n2.`Import Date`
                  AND n1.`Reviewed By` = n2.`Reviewed By`
                  AND n1.xID <> n2.xID
                  LIMIT 20;

      #remove the temp table  data
     #DELETE FROM M_ORIGRES.RSLFix;


END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

It works fine the first time but after the table RSLFix is created I get the error 'Table rslfix already exists'.  DROP TABLE is not working.  Why not?  I just created it with the CREATE TABLE command.

Additional Note:  The DROP command works if I execute it separately.  It only fails when called within the procedure.

Comment: That is unusual; why are you using Query Browser instead of Workbench, or other methods?

Comment: Is this running on multiple connections? Since it is not a temp table, it is possible that among parallel executions one or more could both hit their CREATE after another had.

Comment: you could use `create temporary table` instead. those are automatically deleted when the controlling connection is closed, and temp tables are not shared between connections either.

Comment: No, I'm the only user.  This is just a one-off procedure.  I have tried with the temp table as well but got the same result.  Eventually this procedure (I hope) will loop and create / destroy the table a few times.  So, the connection will remain open.  I just noticed another thing.  The drop command works if I execute it outside of the procedure.  Could it be that the procedure does not have privileges for DROP?

Comment: I can't see anything in the procedure that should really even be capable of yielding that error; the "IF NOT EXISTS" should prevent it on the `CREATE`. ...are you sure you are calling the stored proc on the same server/schema you are editing it on?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  It is a single mySQL instance on my development machine.  It is a completely perplexing issue.  I have seen some comment around the web that the EXISTS clause can cause issues in some versions of mySQL.  Possible workaround was to query the table_schema directly...

Answer (score 0):

try dropping the table at the end of the procedure instead of just deleting the data.